# How do I replace a slice of a dataframe column with values from another dataframe column slice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dataframes with several columns including a timestamp column. I would like to copy the first 1000 timestamps from the second dataframe to the first one.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1.csv)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2.csv)
df1.timestamp.iloc[:1000] = df2.timestamp.iloc[:1000]
```

I tried various things like adding `.copy()` to the right hand side, using `.loc[:1000, 'timestamp']` instead of the columnname.iloc syntax, converting the column series into a numpy array first, but I keep getting errors ranging from "too many indexers", to a directive to use .loc[rowindexing, columnindexing] (which doesn't fix the issue), and other error messages.

Comment: Obne thing, what is `print (df1.info())` and `print (df2.info())` ?

Comment: 1000 rows for the first one with 10 columns, timestamp is type object, 
40000 rows for the second one with 11 columns, timestamp is type object,

Comment: My first solution working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions of columns by names, so possible pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
s = df2.iloc[:1000, df2.columns.get_loc('timestamp')]  
df1.iloc[:1000, df1.columns.get_loc('timestamp')] = s
```

Or if use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with slice index, but working only if length of both DataFrames is greater like `1000`:

```
df1.loc[:df1.index[1000], 'timestamp'] = df2.loc[:df2.index[1000], 'timestamp']
```

---

I think your solution failed, because different lengths of DataFrames.

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "timestamp" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991,
                                    1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'timestamp':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
})

s = df2.iloc[:1000, df2.columns.get_loc('timestamp')]  
df1.iloc[:1000, df1.columns.get_loc('timestamp')] = s
print (df1)
    timestamp
0         4.0
1         5.0
2         4.0
3         5.0
4         5.0
5         4.0
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11        NaN
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "timestamp" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991,
                                    1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'timestamp':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
})

s = df1.iloc[:1000, df1.columns.get_loc('timestamp')]  
df2.iloc[:1000, df2.columns.get_loc('timestamp')] = s

print (df2)
   A  timestamp
0  a       2000
1  b       2001
2  c       2002
3  d       2003
4  e       1990
5  f       1991
```

Comment: Yes, they have different amounts of rows. Still getting SettingWithCopyWarning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - Is possible see your complete code?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - Maybe help `s = df1.iloc[:1000, df1.columns.get_loc('timestamp')].copy()`

Comment: The pandas directive is just a warning, I'm getting an error at a different place in my code, which I can likely fix and is indepdent of this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given df1, df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': range(0,2000)})
df2 = -df1
```

using .loc:

```
df1.loc[:999,'timestamp'] = df2.loc[:999,'timestamp']
df1.loc[997:1002,'timestamp']

997     -997
998     -998
999     -999
1000    1000
1001    1001
1002    1002
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

or using iloc (optionally converting loc -> iloc using `get_loc`)

```
df1.iloc[:1000,0] = df2.iloc[:1000,0]
df1.loc[997:1002,'timestamp']

997     -997
998     -998
999     -999
1000    1000
1001    1001
1002    1002
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

note that the slicing behavior on iloc and loc is differrent.
`.loc` includes the right value, `.iloc` doesn't include it (like in range)

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace a slice of a dataframe with some values based on a condition, for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "timestamp" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991,
                                1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('abcdef'),
     'timestamp':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
    'flag':[0,0,1,1,2,2]
    })

s = df1.iloc[:2, df1.columns.get_loc('timestamp')]  
df2.iloc[df2.flag==1, df2.columns.get_loc('timestamp')] = s
df2
```

[image]