# Replace values in a slice of columns in a pandas dataframe with a value based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, slice

I have a large Pandas dataframe, and want to replace some values in a subset of the columns based on a condition.

Specifically, I want to replace the values that are greater than one with 1 in every column to the right of the 9th column.

Because the dataframe is so large and growing in both the number of rows and columns over time, I cannot manually specify the names of the columns to change values in. Rather, I just need to specify that column 10 and greater should be inspected for values > 1.

After looking at many different Stack Overflow posts and Pandas documentation, I tried:

`df.iloc[df[:,10: ] > 1] = 1`

However, this gives me the error “unhashable type: ‘slice’”.

I then tried:

`df[df.iloc[:, 10:] > 1] = 1`

and

`df[df.loc[:, df.columns[10:]] > 1] = 1`

as per 2 suggestions in the comments, but both of those give me the error “Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value”.

Does anyone know why I’m getting these errors and/or what I should change about my code to avoid them?

Thank you!

Comment: Check `df[df.iloc[:, 10:] > 1] = 1`

Comment: Now I get the error “ ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘iloc’”. @ShubhamSharma

Comment: What about `df[df.loc[:, df.columns[10:]] > 1] = 1`?

Comment: Please check the type of `df` i.e `type(df)` it should come as `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. i guess you have overwritten the variable `df` with a integer value.

Comment: Ah, yes, I accidentally overwrote it. When I fixed that and ran your code from your first comment, I now get the error "Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value." This is because the first 9 of my columns are a mix of strings and ints, something which I cannot change about the dataframe. @ShubhamSharma Do you have any tips here? I don't want to mess with stacking to fix this.

Comment: I get the same mixed-types error while using @Hidden_NB's suggestion too. We're definitely getting somewhere though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

We can use `iloc` to select all the columns to the right of `9th` column, then using `where` we can replace the values in the slice of dataframe where the condition `x.le(1)` is `False`.

```
df.iloc[:, 10:] = df.iloc[:, 10:].where(lambda x: x.le(1), 1)
```

#### 2. [`DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)

Alternatively we can use `clip` where we can define the `upper` limit as `1` which assigns all the values greater than `1` in the slice of dataframe to `1`.

```
df.iloc[:, 10:] = df.iloc[:, 10:].clip(upper=1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what each of these options is doing? I'm not familiar with clip or lambda.

Comment: @jmrpink give me a minute already adding explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I came here searching for *slice of a column*, that means something like `df.loc[10:, column_name]`. If the index is not a range index, the `5:100` need to be replaced with `df.index`. Here is my solution (after some trials and errors) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64022995/11671779):

```py
idx = df.loc[:, data_name].index[10:]  # get index
df.loc[idx, data_name] = 1  # replace
```